# Pass a mutableList from activity A to activity B in Kotlin.

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I'm trying to pass data from activity **A** to activity **B** through intent in Kotlin.

The problem is I have a `videos: MutableList<Video>` and the `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("VIDEOS", videos)` only accepts `ArrayList<out Parcelable>` as arguments.

**Questions**

*. How do I send a mutableList data from activity **A** to activity **B**?

*. Or Do I have to convert it to `ArrayList<Video>` ?

**PS:** `Video`implements Parcelable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Converting it to an `ArrayList` (or storing it as one in the first place?) is the easy solution if you want to stick to passing it through an Intent. There's an [`ArrayList` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/-array-list/-init-.html) that takes a collection as its parameter:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("VIDEOS", ArrayList(videos))
```

Comment: how should behave the second activity when this array get?. because seems when we use "getParcelableArrayListExtra" , it makes error

Answer (score 2):

For those asking how the Parcelable class is created, this is the solution I came up with in Kotlin

The Parcelable Class:

```
@Parcelize
data class ExampleModel(
        var stringOne: String,
        var stringTwo: String): Parcelable
```

Then in Activity A you can create an ArrayList and send it via intent to Activity B

```
private var exampleMutableList: MutableList<ExampleModel> = arrayListOf()
exampleMutableList.add(ExampleModel("hello", "world"))
intent.putExtra("example", ArrayList(exampleMutableList))
```

And in Activity B we can receive our ArrayList:

```
exampleMutableList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<ExampleModel>("example") as ArrayList<ExampleModel>
```

All the best!

Comment: This is a pretty complete answer. should be accepted one.