# Android kotlin - pass and retrieve MutableList from Activity A to Activity B

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

I need to pass it from recyclerview

I tried:

```
            val extras = Bundle()
            extras.putString("userNickname", meme.nickname)
            extras.putParcelableArray("memes", ArrayList(memes))

            val i = Intent(context, UserMemes::class.java)
            i.putExtras(extras)
            context.startActivity(i)
```

based on this answer:
[Pass a mutableList from activity A to activity B in Kotlin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541446/pass-a-mutablelist-from-activity-a-to-activity-b-in-kotlin)

and get the error `Type mismatch: inferred type is Memes! but Parcelable! was expected` on `ArrayList(memes)`

I also need to know how to retrieve it on activity B

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add your `UserMemes` activity code.

Comment: There is only val userNickname = intent.getStringExtra("userNickname") inside onCreate so far

Comment: Kindly refer the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14333555/6903609. Make the Memes class implements Serializable

Comment: bundle.putSerializable("memesss", memes) gives Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<Memes> but Serializable? was expected on memes

Comment: Please see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) to learn about starting an Activity, your intent is not built correctly.

Comment: @mightyWOZ I did it many times this way, just without i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("memes", ArrayList(memes)) which I changed in the question now by putting it into extras but I still have same error